# long text area ( formula )

Tags: formula, formula-field, long-text-area, count

I am trying to find number of lines of long text area field using (formula).[As formula field doesn't supports long text area](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhEAAS) workaround is to use workflow field update formula([workflow field update formula supports long text area](http://linkingto.blogspot.de/2011/08/salesforce-long-text-area-and-formulas.html)).How to get number of lines of long text area field in formula or Do I need to achieve this in trigger ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645357/salesforce-apex-count-number-of-line-breaks-in-text-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
    trigger UpdateCount on my_object__c (after insert,after update) {

    list<Id> lpIdList = new list<Id>();

        for(my_object__c  lp : trigger.new){

            if(trigger.isInsert){
              if((lp.my_long_text_area__c != null)){
              lpIdList.add(lp.Id);
             }
            }

            if(trigger.isUpdate){
               if((Trigger.oldMap.get(lp.Id).my_long_text_area__c != Trigger.newMap.get(lp.Id).my_long_text_area__c) && (Trigger.newMap.get(lp.Id).my_long_text_area__c != null)){
                 lpIdList.add(lp.Id);
              }
            }
        }

     list<my_object__c> lpList = [select id,Line_Count__c,my_long_text_area__c from my_object__c where id in:lpIdList];

    for(LNP_Request__c lp:lpList){
         list<String> totalLines =  lp.my_long_text_area__c.split('\n');
         lp.Line_Count__c = totalLines.size();
      }

    if(lpList.size()>0){
       update lpList; 
    }

  }
```